# Django Rest Framework - unit testing viewset extra actions

Tags: django-rest-framework

If I take the example from the official documentation:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.set_password(serializer.data['password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'status': 'password set'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How would I write my unit test to test the success of the action, and its failure?  I'm not sure what the syntax would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be tested like any other endpoint, except it has a different URL. For example, I have a endpoint to allow users to update their existing passwords. So:

- I created a new TestCase for that endpoint
- Then I run my usual tests, which are:

  - Checking my validation/fails. Here: strong enough password? Do they match? etc.
  - Checking a successful call
  - Checking permissions/access

Here's a full fledged example. Some of the code is missing (ie I didnt copy my custom parent classes and what not) but it gives you an idea:

```py
# Extra action
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @action(detail=True, methods=["post"])
    def update_password(self, request, pk=None):
        """Updates our user's current password"""
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_valid_serializer(user, data=request.data)
        user = serializer.save()
        user.send_password_updated_email(async_=True)
        return Response(None, HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

The associated Serializer. There are custom validators for the other fields, but they come from my parent `PasswordValidationMixin`

```py
class UpdatePasswordSerializer(PasswordValidationMixin, ImprovedSerializer):
    """Similar to 'OverridePasswordSerializer' but asks for the user's current password"""

    current_password = PasswordField()
    password = PasswordField()
    confirm_password = PasswordField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ["password", "confirm_password", "current_password"]

    def update(self, user, validated_data):
        """
        Updates the user's password and returns the instance
        :param User user:
        :param dict validated_data:
        :return: The updated user
        :rtype: User
        """
        user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
        user.save()
        return user

    def validate_current_password(self, current_password):
        """
        Checks the value matches the user's current password
        :param str current_password:
        :return: The raw password
        :rtype: str
        """
        user = self.instance
        if not user.check_password(current_password):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid current password")
        return current_password
```

And then I write my units tests:

```py
class TestUpdatePassword(Base):
    """TestCase for the `update_password` action"""

    url_template = f"{SERVICE_URL}/{{id}}/update_password/"
    http_method_name = "POST"
    success_code = 204

    def setUp(self):
        """Creates and authenticates a user, then prepares a URL and payload"""
        self.payload = {
            "current_password": "Str0ngP4ssw0rD!",
            "password": "Str0ngP4ssw0rD!!!",
            "confirm_password": "Str0ngP4ssw0rD!!!",
        }
        self.user = UserFactory(password=self.payload["current_password"])
        self.api_client.force_authenticate(self.user)
        self.detail_url = self.url(context={"id": self.user.id})

    def test_permissions(self):
        """Tests only the owner can reset his own password"""
        admin = AdminFactory(password=self.payload["current_password"])
        self.assert_owner_permissions(self.detail_url, self.user, admin, self.payload)
        sleep(0.4)  # For the email to be sent

    def test_current_password(self):
        """Tests the user must provide the correct current password"""
        self.payload["current_password"] = "invalidPassword"
        response = self.http_method(self.detail_url, data=self.payload)
        assert response.status_code == 400
        assert len(response.data["current_password"]) > 0

    def test_password(self):
        """Tests the user must provide a strong-enough new password"""
        self.assert_password_strength(self.detail_url, self.payload)

    def test_confirm_password(self):
        """Tests the confirmation password must match the new password"""
        self.assert_matching_password(self.detail_url, self.payload)

    def test_success(self):
        """Tests the user can successfully update his own password"""
        response = self.http_method(self.detail_url, data=self.payload)
        assert response.status_code == self.success_code
        # Check the password has been updated
        update_user = User.objects.get(id=self.user.id)
        assert not update_user.check_password(self.payload["current_password"])
        assert update_user.check_password(self.payload["password"])
        # Check the email was sent
        subject = UserEmailTemplate.PASSWORD_UPDATED.subject
        self.assert_email_was_sent(subject, to=[update_user.email], async_=True)
```